# Why do the std smart pointer type destructors not inherit the noexcept dtor status of the pointed to object

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, smart-pointers, noexcept

In C++11, my understanding is that by default destructors are implicitly `noexcept(true)`, except that:

If I have a class `C` that has a destructor explicitly marked `noexcept(false)` (presumably because it throws for some odd reason, and I'm aware that you shouldn't, and why) then the destructor of any class that derives from `C` or contains a member of type `C` also becomes `noexcept(false)`.

However, a class which contains a `std::shared_ptr<C>` apparently does not automatically have its destructor toggled to `noexcept(false)`, and the same is true for containing a `std::weak_ptr<C>`, `std::unique_ptr<C>`, etc.

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

struct Normal {
    ~Normal() {
    }
};

struct ThrowsInDtor {
    ~ThrowsInDtor() noexcept(false) {
        throw 42;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;
};

template<typename T>
struct UniquePtrWrapper {
    std::unique_ptr<T> t;
};

template<typename T>
struct SharedPtrWrapper {
    std::shared_ptr<T> t;
};

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<Normal>::value, "A"); // OK
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_destructible<ThrowsInDtor>::value, "B"); // OK

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<Wrapper<Normal>>::value, "C"); // OK
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_destructible<Wrapper<ThrowsInDtor>>::value, "D"); // OK

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<UniquePtrWrapper<Normal>>::value, "E"); // OK
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_destructible<UniquePtrWrapper<ThrowsInDtor>>::value, "F"); // FAILS

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<SharedPtrWrapper<Normal>>::value, "G"); // OK
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_destructible<SharedPtrWrapper<ThrowsInDtor>>::value, "H"); // FAILS
```

It seems odd to me that F and H fail. I had expected that the noexcept status of the destructor of the owned/referenced type would propagate to the smart pointer destructor, presumably by way of a noexcept expression like `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value)` on the smart pointer destructor declaration.

However the standard makes no mention of this, and the standard library code I've looked at doesn't do this.

Does anyone know why it is that the standard smart pointers don't propagate the noexcept destructor status of the instantiating type to the smart pointer destructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<T>` is designed to be usable with an incomplete `T`, hence there is no way to get the information you are asking for when declaring its destructor. Also, you can do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<void> dummy = std::make_shared<T>(); // for some complete T
```

Now what should `noexcept` say for `std::shared_ptr<void>`? It's a run-time-information from `std::shared_ptr`'s POV.

For `std::unique_ptr`, there is

> #### 20.7.1.2.2 unique_ptr destructor [unique.ptr.single.dtor]
>
> <sup>1</sup> `~unique_ptr();`
>
> *Requires:* The expression `get_deleter()(get())` shall be well formed, shall have well-defined behavior, and shall not throw exceptions. [ *Note:* The use of `default_delete` requires `T` to be a complete type. *—endnote*]

Which means that the deleter needs to make sure that it doesn't throw - which does *not* necessarily depend on the destructor of `T`, i.e., when you use a null-deleter.

Comment: This doesn't say anything about `std::unique_ptr`, though, which needs the type to be complete at the point the destructor is instantiated and invoked.

Comment: @Xeo It does not even necessarily invoke the destructor of object it points to. Which might also be true for `std::shared_ptr` now that I think about it. Anyways, updated the answer.

Comment: I meant the destructor of the `std::unique_ptr` itself, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Xeo No confusion, that part was clear. The point is that even then you could not add a "correct" noexcept specification (in the OPs sense): Just think of `std::unique_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>>`. My head is spinning, I think this is a) a sign to go to bed now and b) there are good reasons why destructors should never throw exceptions :)